# Command Line Parser NUGet Package getting simple example program to work

Tags: c#, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

I'm finding this very challenging and I appreciate any help you are willing of offer me.

Currently I'm trying to implement Command Line Parser  (https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline).

I just want to get a basic example application working and I am stuck.

Ultimately I want the following pattern

MyProgram -soureid 1231 -domain alpha

Where I get sourceid and domain as valid variables. sourceid would have the value of 1231 and domain would have the value of "alpha".

This is a C# .net core application (2.3) and I'm running Visual Studio 2017.

Here is the code that I have so far...

```
    using System;
using CommandLine;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main(String[] args)
        {
            var options = new SomeOptions();

            CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, typeof(SomeOptions));

            Console.WriteLine(options.Age);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    class SomeOptions
    {
        [Option('n', "name", Required = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Option('a', "age")]
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This code does not work. When I pass -n Jason I get this..

```
CommandLineArgumentParsing 1.0.0
Copyright (C) 2019 CommandLineArgumentParsing

ERROR(S):
  Verb '-n' is not recognized.

  --help       Display this help screen.

  --version    Display version information.

0
```

I believe this issue is with this line..

```
 CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, typeof(SomeOptions));
```

It seems like this line should be this..

```
 CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, typeof(options));
```

However the compiler is complaining that "'options' is a variable but is used like a type"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

I figured this out about two seconds after I asked the question..

Replace..

```
CommandLine.Parser.Default.ParseArguments(args, typeof(SomeOptions));
```

With...

```
Parser.Default.ParseArguments<SomeOptions>(args).WithParsed(parsed => options = parsed);
```